# Python - Mongoengine advanced query list field

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine, listfield

I have a list of lists, like so:

```
li = [[('A', 'one'), ('A', 'two')], [('B', 'three'), ('B', 'four')]]
```

and I need to query a mongo database to get all objects whose list field contains at least ONE item in each sublist of `li`.  Ex: items that have either [('A', 'one') OR ('A', 'two')] AND either [('B', 'three') OR ('B', 'four')] ...

I am using mongoengine, but that may be able to change if I can use something else to get this done.  So right now I am doing many queries like so, to avoid getting duplicate entries:

```
final = set()
for sublist in li:
    query = Obj.objects(list_field__in=sublist)
    final &= set(query)
```

The problem is that this is very slow when dealing with large query results (making the set takes a very long time, I believe).  Is there a way that I can speed this up?  Specifically, is there a way that I can avoid set/list creation from the query results?

I would really like to be able to somehow write something like this:

```
query = Obj.objects(list_field__in=li[0] AND list_field__in=li[1] AND ...)
```

Edit: The answer below does not work upon further testing, because mongoengine does not allow `Q(field=x) & Q(field=y)`

Edit2: Here is the equivalent mongoDB query that I want to do:

```
db.obj.find({ "$and": [
    {"list_field": {"$in":
        [["A", "one"], ["A", "two"]]
    }},
    {"list_field": {"$in":
        [["B", "three"], ["B", "four"]]
    }}
]})
```

Can I do this in mongoengine?  It will not let me do a query with `Q(list_field__in=[('A', 'one'), ('A', 'two')]) | Q(list_field__in=[('B', 'three'), ('B', 'four')])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try it [through the Q class](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries):

```
  filter = reduce(Q.__and__, map(lambda x: Q(list_field__in=x), li))
  Obj.objects(filter)
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I need!  I love the use of `reduce` as well, but I will put your more verbose answer in this comment in case someone prefers that.
`filter = Q()
  for sublist in li:
      filter = filter & Q(list_field__in=sublist)
  Obj.objects(filter)`

Comment: Actually when I try it with a more complex query it does not work.  I get InvalidQueryError because it does not allow to have `Q(list_field__in=x) & Q(list_field__in=y)`, since `list_field` is the same in both `Q`s.

Comment: Could you try: `filter = Q()
for subli in li:
    subfilter = Q()
    for elem in subli:
        subfilter = subfilter | Q(list_field=elem)
    filter = filter & subfilter`

Comment: I actually tried exactly that already, but it doesn't allow that either.